# Not picking up variable in expression correctly - Ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm trying the following -

```
---
- name: Test
  hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  
  vars: 
    before: "groups.{{ hosts[0] }}_group_name"
    after: "{{ before }}" # This equals {{ groups.test_group_name }}
  
  roles: 
    - test-check
```

Just an explanation: I'm feeding hosts in when executing the playbook as a 'var'. In this case, `var = test`. The expected var string for `before` would be `groups.test_group_name` which is a group that contains multiple hosts in my inventory. However, when I execute this, after remains as `groups.test_group_name` instead of the expected array of hosts.

Does anybody know how I can remedy this? If I hard-code the host_name (test) into the after var, it picks it up, but if I don't, it doesn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are trying to do *pseudocode:* `{{ eval(before) }}` but that is not how ansible, or jinja2, work. Thankfully, `groups` is a normal python `dict` and thus is subject to the `__getitem__` syntax `[]` to dynamically look up keys

Thus, you likely want:

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  vars:
    after: "{{ groups[ hosts[0]+'_group_name' ] }}"
  tasks:
  - debug: var=after
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you mdaniel for the explanation and example.